# preg_replace_callback syntax works in PHP 5.3 but not in PHP 5.2

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.2, preg-replace-callback

Here is the small php example :

```
echo '<pre>';

// Execute httpd.exe -V to find apache version
exec('"E:\Program Files\AMPPS\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -V', $out, $ret);

// preg_replace_callback to fetch version
echo $apver = preg_replace_callback('/Server version: Apache\/(.*?) \((.*?)\)/is', function ($matches){ return $apache_version = trim($matches[1]); } ,$out[0]);
echo "\n";
echo "\n";

// Test this file with PHP 5.3
exec('"E:\Program Files\AMPPS\php\php.exe" -l "'.__FILE__.'"', $out1, $ret1);
print_r(array($out1, $ret1));

// Test this file with PHP 5.2
exec('"E:\Program Files\AMPPS\php-5.2\php.exe" -l "'.__FILE__.'"', $out2, $ret2);
print_r(array($out2, $ret2));
```

Output :

```
2.4.6

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => No syntax errors detected in E:\Program Files\AMPPS\www\preg_replace.php
        )

    [1] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in E:\Program Files\AMPPS\www\preg_replace.php on line 5
            [2] => Errors parsing E:\Program Files\AMPPS\www\preg_replace.php
        )

    [1] => -1
)
```

I need a syntax that will work in both PHP 5.2 and 5.3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) definitions using `function` keyword is available only since PHP 5.3 Prior to 5.3 version you can use only [create_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) to define anonymous functions.

Comment: Done. I will create a callback function outside. And specify its name in the argument. Cannot accept answers so soon. Hehe.

Comment: Can you change your second link from `/ru/` to `/en/` please :)

Comment: oops. Proxy error, thanks. That's "smart google" substitutes external IP location language :p